# VB.net - Connect to Database

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, winforms

I got mysql database in the phpmyadmin, and i try to connect to the database from my application.

My connection string is:

```
Server=12.919.18.12;Port=3306;Database=hbd;Uid=hb;Pwd=123;
```

An exception occurs:

```
"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."
```

Do I need to install mysql or something?

(I just imported MySql.Data.dll and tryied it. Is there anything I have forgotten? I checked the ip pinging my website).

Comment: 919 is not valid in an IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Connection strings for MySQL](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql)
>   is pretty helpful in terms of connection strings. Your connection
>   string seems to be invalid.

You may check mysql server is working or not and you can add port number of mysql in connection string like this

> **"Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"**

---

*Other reason MySql might be configured to listen to only the local host.*

Follow the following links for more information:
[Enabling MySQL Remote Access - MySQL connection only works from local machine](http://www.razorsql.com/docs/support_mysql_local.html)
[Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/368297/Unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-MySQL-ho)

Comment: yea.. this is same with sql server .. you have to enable access to remote connection.. but you should check your connection string.. there may be problem.. if not then some privileges problem with the user..

Comment: correct your IP address of server then let us know that whether it is working or not

Comment: im used remote server , i cant connect to remote server?

Comment: check your remote server name and put it in the connection.. may be it will resolve the issue..

Comment: Glad that you fixed..you can check this - [How can I access a remote MySQL database?](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?34,36527,39182). do you mysql database on hosting provider??

Answer (score 0):

If the datababase is local, try localhost or 127.0.0.1 as the IP address.

Is the server on your network? If so, the IP is invalid. If I were you, I'd try to check the IP with the person who gave it to you.

Comment: phpmyadmin means ? if you install local machine then its called `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

**IP is invalid  *12.919.18.12***

```
Server=12.919.18.12;Port=3306;Database=hbd;Uid=hb;Pwd=123;
```

IP block is **< 256**

Comment: i used this ip for the example bro

Comment: then how can we find your exact error? and how can we help ? provide some code

Answer (score 0):

the connection string is correct but as ive read a lot of forums they all have the same problems as you do. my solution is that if your trying to create a network base system on a LAN type network you should use XAMPP or WAMPP but i prefer xampp and double check if your accounts or users have an Admin or any other user name for your connection and then see if they have granted all the privileges and with password of course.
Here is the ff instructions:
Open Xammp
Then open a web browser then open 127.0.0.1 or localhost.
click phpmyadmin then at the top click privileges.
add user and make it sure allow all privileges and check all access.
then connect again using the same connection string with the proper user and password.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is RESOLVED :)

try to put the PORT in the end like :
"Server=12.919.18.12;Database=hbd;Uid=hb;Pwd=123;Port:3306;"